# Eigenvalue of inertia tensor not returning inertia tensor of principal axes

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm running a cubic satellite attitude simulation in MATLAB and I need to calculate its principal moments of inertia. To do so I thought I'd do the following:
Calculate the inertia tensor using a frame located at one of its edges and then calculate it's eigenvalues, which I think should return the principal moments of inertia about a frame F, aligned with the principal axes. I decided to test this by calculating the moments of inertia about the COM which I know that due to symmetry are the principal moments of inertia. However the eigenvalues from the first tensor are not the same as the tensor about the COM.I don't understand why! Could anyone clear it up for me? 
I'm using m=1.33 w=0.11 b=0.12 c=0.13 as data.
Using for the tensors:
\begin{equation}about \; edge:
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{m}{3}(c^2+b^2) & -\frac{m}{4}ab & -\frac{m}{4}ac \\
-\frac{m}{4}ba & \frac{m}{3}(a^2+c^2) & -\frac{m}{4}bc \\
-\frac{m}{4}ca & -\frac{m}{4}cb & \frac{m}{3}(a^2+b^2) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\ and \; about \; the \; COM:
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{m}{12}(c^2+b^2) & 0& 0 \\
0 & \frac{m}{12}(a^2+c^2)& 0 \\
0 & 0& \frac{m}{12}(a^2+b^2) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
 The eigenvalues of the tensor about the edge yield:
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0032 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0.0175 & 0 \\
0 & 0& 0.0178 \\
\end{bmatrix}
while the tensor about COM is:
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0035 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0.0032 & 0 \\
0 & 0& 0.0029 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Why is that? What did I not understand?

Comment: you're calculating the inertia tensor at different points, so the eigenvalues are different. There is no contradiction here. If however you calculated the inertia tensor at the same point, but you used a different basis (for example inertia tensor about COM, with one basis being the eigenbasis, and the second basis being any other random one) then you'll get a different matrix representation, but the eigenvalues will be the same.

Comment: I think I see what you mean! But then what is the physical meaning of the eigenvalues about the edge frame? Surely it's not the principal axes? But having what you said in mind, am I right to assume that to calculate the moments of inertia of the principal axes through the CoM I have to calculate the products and moments of inertia at the CoM, and then get the eigenvalues from that matrix?

Comment: Pick any point on the rigid body. There is an associated inertia tensor at that point. Once you choose a basis, you can represent the tensor as a 3x3 matrix. The physical meaning of the elements of that matrix is that they roughly speaking "measure the difficulty of rotation in a certain direction". In particular of you choose the eigenbasis, then the matrix will be diagonal. Then the diagonal entries (which are the eigenvalues) are a measure of how difficult it is to rotate about the respective axis (which passes through the point we chose from the beginning) determined by the eigenvector.

Comment: Ok! So I will consider an off-centered CoM and pick a reference frame centered at CoM. I will calculate the inertia tensor and then its eigenvalues will be the principal moments of inertia. Right?

Comment: Well I'm getting negative moments so I guess it's not working...

Comment: What do you mean by an off-centered COM, with a reference frame centered at COM? If your goal is to calculate the principal moments of inertia (i.e the eigenvalues of the inertia tensor at the center of mass), then you need to calculate the inertia tensor AT the center of mass, and then calculate its eigenvalues. I'm not sure why you're confusing two different points.

Comment: I mean the rigid body's mass is not uniformely distributed so the CoM is not at its geometrical center. So I was saying I calculate the inertia tensor of a set of axis that is centered on that CoM and has its axes parallel to the body's edges. I would then calculate the eigenvalues of that tensor which would be the principal moments of inertia. I think the reason why I got negative values has more to do with the parallel axis theorem I used than with what you told me earlier! I think I got what you meant!